# SQL query: pivot data by 1st and 2nd date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
 Id   Date   Value
 111  1/1/19 1
 111  2/1/19 2
 222  5/1/19 4
 222  4/1/19 3
```

Is there a way I can rearrange the data into something like this:

```
 Id   OldDate  NewDate  OldValue NewValue
 111  1/1/19   1/2/19   1        2
 222  4/1/19   5/1/19   3        4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date,
             lag(value) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date is not null;
```